# Xamarin Forms with Prism MasterDetail navigation

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, prism, xamarin.forms

I have started building an app on Xamarin Studio using Prism with Xamarin.Forms. My issue is that I can't seem to find a snippet of code as an example of MasterDetail navigation inside the app.

Every time I navigate to a page it just renders a new view on top of the previous master view. Is there an example somewhere, or instructions on how to use switchable views in order to achieve master/detail navigation with prism on xamarin? I have found some prism examples for windows forms applications but nothing specific to xamarin forms.

Thank you in advance and sorry for the generalized question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out the sandbox sample that is in the Prism repo.. It's actually quite simple.

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Sandbox/Xamarin/HelloWorld

You just have to call navigate from your MasterDetilPage ViewModel.  This will set the Detail page accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much, that example saved the day. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Brian I saw this sample but you are using normal button instead menu list and also your are not using Details page, do you have anything in Prism where you are using MasterDetailsPage with Details page ?

Comment: The sandbox sample is constantly changing as I work on new features.  As I stated above in the answer. Simply call NavigateAsync from the MasterDetailPage ViewModel.  It will set the detail automatically.  If you need to navigate to it initially, then just build your path NavigateAsync("MasterDetailPage/DetailPage");

Comment: It currently shows how to use the MasterDetailPage and change the detail.  Updating the Master from a Detail view is not a common user experience

Comment: @BrianLagunas what about scenarios where say a custom title bar is implemented. I am trying to toggle the Master IsPresented property from the detail page's View Model at a button click. I have also asked a question about it here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267942/how-to-show-menu-in-masterdetail-page-when-using-prism-and-custom-title-bar

Comment: @BrianLagunas thanks for this answer its working as expected. I'm just wondering what is prism doing for that under the hood (automatically set the detail ?) ?

Comment: @BrianLagunas This link is now broken, is there an updated link that we could get? This seems to be exactly the answer I need if I could look at an example