# HelloWorld sample code not working on Android: Back button not visible

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I got the sample app from
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/tree/master/Sandbox/Xamarin/HelloWorld

I tested it on Android 6:

1. Run the app from sample code (**no modifications**), it shows MainPage
2. Tap on ViewA from the menu, it navigates to ViewA, but there is no back button in the app bar.

Hitting device back button works, it navigates back to MainPage.

The behavior I am expecting is to see the back button in the bar too.

**UPDATE**

I'm debugging Prism, and I can see clearly that Prism's `PageNavigationService` navigates to `ViewA` by just calling `currentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page, animated)`. 
I can see that the Xamarin Forms's `NavigationImpl` has the `NavigationStack` with two pages, `MainPage` and `ViewA`. So the `MainPage` is still there in the navigation stack, but for some reason the back button is not visible.

**ANSWER!**
@lowleetak discovered that there is a call somewhere in the sample which hides the back button!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app start in MasterDetail page. Where the MasterPage is the Menu and DetailPage is the MyNavigationPage/MainPage initially.

When you click ViewA from menu, it is changing the DetailPage from MainPage to MyNavigationPage/ViewA. It is the root/initial page in the navigation stack of the DetailPage. So, there is no Back button showing.

Comment: So the `navigationService` injected in the `MyMasterDetailViewModel` is navigating by replacing the Details? How to navigate to ViewA so that the back button is visible?

Comment: I'm debugging Prism and I don't think what you're saying is correct. I can see clearly that Prism's `PageNavigationService` navigates to `ViewA` by just calling `currentPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page, animated)`. I can see that the Xamarin Forms's `INavigation` has the `NavigationStack` with two pages, MainPage and ViewA. So the MainPage is still there in the navigation stack. Why isn't the back button being displayed?

Comment: Calling navigate in MyMasterDetailViewModel will change the detail page. I can't find the documentation on this. But Brian Lagunas mention this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604135/xamarin-forms-with-prism-masterdetail-navigation

Comment: If you want to call to ViewA with back button, then you should call navigate in MainPageViewModel

Comment: I added a button in `MainPage.xaml` and in `SomeOtherViewModel` I added `ShowViewACommand = new DelegateCommand(() => navigationService.NavigateAsync("ViewA"));` It shows `ViewA` but no back button.

Comment: Apparently in ViewA.xaml.cs is having the code to hide the back button. Line 13: NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false). Also, I have checked the NavigationStack in ViewA if trigger from left menu. You are correct that MainPage is still in the stack, I'm quite confuse too. I guess if we really want to clear the stack, we should use absolute navigation URL in MyMasterDetailViewModel.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize it's hiding the back button somewhere! Thanks for checking out the stack, at least I know I am not crazy...

Comment: Not sure maybe I should close this issue? But what I am actually trying to do is when an item is selected from a `ListView` in `Master`, I want to navigate from `MainPage` to `ViewA` but keep back button visible. Sounds easy but I just can't get it to work right now. I think I will open a separate question

Comment: Using NavigateAsync in SomeOtherViewModel to ViewA will have the Back button.
I just finished checking, the weird issue of MainPage is still keeping in NavigationStack after click in LeftMenu is because the samples has set ClearNavigationStackOnNavigation to false in MyNavigationPage.xaml.cs. Remove this, calling NavigateAsync in MyMasterDetailViewModel will not longer keep MasterPage in navigation stack.

Comment: I  see a comment in the code `//42548` seem to be related to a bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42548

Comment: I am confused about `ClearNavigationStackOnNavigation` too. I am confused why do you need to override it and return `false`. Isn't `NavigationPage` supposed to push pages to stack? Why do I have to set that property to `false`?